# Quick suggestion on php multiple file uploading

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using thid code this basically helping me getting file which user drops on browser and then post it to php and echoing file name but the problem is with the array in php when ever i drop 2 files and call the php file and try to echo the count of files it gives me 5 always and it echos the 2 file names and + othes as undefined index.... and if i upload 5 files it show all 5 with no problem....plz help me why this is happing...

Here is my jquery code:

```
function handleFiles(droppedFiles) {
  var uploadFormData = new FormData($("#yourregularuploadformId")[0]);
  if(droppedFiles.length > 0) {
    // checks if any files were dropped
    for(var f = 0; f < droppedFiles.length; f++) {
      // for-loop for each file dropped
      alert(droppedFiles[f]['name']);
      uploadFormData.append("files[]",droppedFiles[f]);
      // adding every file to the form so you could upload multiple files
    }
  }

 // the final ajax call
 alert(uploadFormData);
 $.ajax({
   url : "try.php?size="+s, // use your target
   type : "POST",
   data : uploadFormData,
   cache : false,
   contentType : false,
   processData : false,
   success : function(ret) {
     alert(ret);
   }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Here is my php code :

```
if(isset($_FILES["files"])) {
  for ($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['files']);$i++) {
    echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
    echo "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Change it to: `if(isset($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];`

Comment: thanks worked like a charm thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work this way. `$_FILES` is an associative array containing the uploaded files, indexed by the field name. Each entry has exactly five elements: `name`,`tmp_name`,`size`,`type` and `error`. Each of these elements is an array containing as many elements as the uploaded files.

So if you `count($_FILES['files'])`, the result will always be 5. But if you `count($_FILES['files'][$xyz])` where `$xyz` is any of the above keys, *that* will be the number of uploaded files.

So your code would work like this, for example:

```
if(isset($_FILES["files"]))
  {
  for ($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['files']['name']);$i++) 
    {
    echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
    echo "\n";
    }
  }
```

or better yet (for readability, if nothing else):

```
if(isset($_FILES["files"]))
  {
  $filenames=$_FILES['files']['name'];
  for ($i=0;$i<count($filenames);$i++) 
    {
    echo $filenames[$i];
    echo "\n";
    }
  }
```